# Python Watchdog Custom Event Handler Not Firing Correctly

Tags: windows, python-watchdog

I'm using Python's watchdog module to listen for created events on a certain directory. Where I do some processing on newly created .csv files. When I test my code with nothing in the handler the watchdog fires correctly for all pasted/created files, but when I add my code/logic inside the handler it fires less than expected (52/60 files for example).
OS used: Windows 10, code is expected to work on a Windows server.
Python version: 3.7.3

Code:

```
import time 
from watchdog.observers import Observer 
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from error_handling import ErrorHandler
import os
from timeloop import Timeloop
from datetime import timedelta
import json 
from fill_data import OnMyWatch2


class OnMyWatch:
    # Set the directory on watch 
    watchDirectory = "."
  
def __init__(self): 
    self.observer1 = Observer()

def run(self):
    self.observer1.schedule(Handler() , self.watchDirectory, recursive = True)
    self.observer1.start()
    try: 
        while True: 
            time.sleep(1) 
    except: 
        self.observer1.stop() 
        print("Observer Stopped") 

    self.observer1.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

@staticmethod
def on_any_event(event):

    if event.is_directory: 
        return None

    elif event.event_type == 'created':
        try:
            
            # Event is created, you can process it now 
            print("Watchdog received created event - % s." % event.src_path)
            
            pathlower = str(event.src_path).lower()
            if ".csv" in pathlower:
                print("File is csv file")
                # Once any code is added here the problem happens
                # Example:
                # df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, names= ALL_INI.columnlistbundle.split("|"), sep="|", encoding='latin-1', engine='python')
                # arraySelectedColumnsBundle = ALL_INI.selectedcolumnsbundle.split(",")
                # bundle_df = df[np.array(arraySelectedColumnsBundle)]
            else:
                print("File is not csv file")
        except Exception as e:
            ErrorHandler(0, 'In Observer ', '-7', 'Exception ' + str(e), '', 1, '')
             

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if os.path.isdir("."):
        watch = OnMyWatch() 
        watch.run()
```